# If the left-inverse matrix is multiplied to the right of the matrix, why would the result be an zeros added identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I took a linear algebra class, and the professor said that if you multiply the left-inverse to the right-side of the matrix, the result is a zeros added identity matrix as shown in figure [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E9bZ.jpg).

1. for left inverse, $A_{m \times n}, m>n$

$A^{-1}_{n \times m}A_{m \times n} = I_{n \times n}$
(figure [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjuUK.jpg))

$A_{m \times n}A^{-1}_{n \times m} = B_{m \times m}$ where $B_{m \times m}$ is a zeros added identity matrix (please refer to the figure [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E9bZ.jpg))

2. for right inverse, $A_{m \times n}, m<n$

$A_{m \times n} A^{-1}_{n \times m} = I_{m \times m}$
(figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrFnq.jpg))

$A^{-1}_{n \times m} A_{m \times n}  = C_{n \times n}$ where $C_{n \times n}$ is a zeros added identity matrix (please refer to the figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgHSJ.jpg))

Why would the result of multiplying the left inverse to the right be a zeros added identity matrix? Is there a book or web site covering this?

Comment: You can immediately see that the claim cannot be true: there is no reason why there would be a preference for the upper-left corner over the lower-right. If You doubt, check what happens to a product $AB$ if you rotate each of $AB$ by a half-turn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't true that reversing the order of multiplication with a one-sided inverse results in such a matrix. For example, $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}$ so the left one is left inverse to the right.

But reversing them:

$\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1/2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}$

You would need some additional conditions on the left inverse for the statement you cited to hold.

Comment: You are right. The professor seems to be confused with other things.